# subtração de valores entre colunas diferente de uma mesma tabela

Tags: sql, mvc

é o seguinte, estou tentando obter o resultado de uma subtração através de um query entre colunas diferentes de uma mesma tabela.

tenho a seguinte tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como podem ver na tabela, tenho a coluna tipo_lancamento, que pode ser (despesa ou receita) e para cada tipo é inserido um valor que é armazenado na coluna valor, até ai tudo certo. Porém após inserir os valores na tabela, preciso obter o resultado da subtração entre os valores do tipo_lancamento = receita menos valores do tipo_lancamento = despesa.

estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas está dando erro

SELECT SUM(valor) WHERE tipo_lancamento = 'receita' -  SUM(valor) tipo_lancamento = 'despesa' FROM lancamentos;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu trocaria o `tipo_lancamento` por um tipo int para ganhar mais performance e ser mais preciso.
Faltou colocar o nome da tabela em outra parte também
mas o resto eu faria assim:

em Firebird:

```
Select (
    (SELECT SUM(valor) from lancamentos WHERE tipo_lancamento = 'receita') 
   - (SELECT SUM(valor) from lancamentos WHERE tipo_lancamento = 'despesa')
)from rdb$database
```

Comment: muito obg Gabriel, seguindo sua solução, consegui realizar a consulta. Agora estou tentando adaptar essa query na estrutura  mvc.